# disabling ASP.NEt Validtor such that its disabled on postback

Tags: asp.net, javascript, jquery

I am trying to disable ASP.Net Validator such that its disabled on postback.

I am disabling the validator on client side using

```
$('.c_MyValidator').each(function() {
     ValidatorEnable(document.getElementById($(this).attr('id')), false);
});
```

but when the page postbacks, my page is still invalid. 
I am in UserControl (.ascx) so no override for Validate() for me.

How can I disable the validator such that its enabled=false when the page postbacks.

Any ideas?

Comment: Validation is usually what you WANT to happen on postback. Can you explain the ulterior motive a bit more?

Comment: yeah sure.. well there is similar small version of the whole scenario, i click on a check box  "Enable/disable Date" which shows and hides the date textbox to enter a date or not. So I got a required field validator on that date textbox. So validator needs to function if the checbox is checked not otherwise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an example for your scenario [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479045.aspx#aspplusvalid_clientside). Basically in server side code, set the enabled property of the validator to the checked property of the checkbox (as well as call the client ValidatorEnable). Use the Page_Load event of your user control because there is no Validate method.

```
public partial class CheckboxAndValidator : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        validator.Enabled = cbControlValidation.Checked;
    }
}
```

What you can't do is validate your *page* in the Page_Load event. This is too early and needs to be done later in the page life-cycle once the user control has done it's bit.